# How do I convert adobe xd to html css (vue)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, converters

I want to make a single page application using vue.js. I get a reference like this https://coreui.io/vue/ to make it. my colleague has made a prototype using adobe xd. and my job is to convert it to html css and it will make it functional and connect to api. Can I convert it automatically? or do I have to convert it manually. if it's not possible to convert it automatically, is there a template that can help me to convert to html css? i am weak in css. so i need a reference. so I can convert quickly

please help me several options. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to convert manually 
However, the export to HTML/CSS/JS feature has been asked before by the community many times and the Adobe team is currently working on it (check [this](https://adobexd.uservoice.com/forums/353007-adobe-xd-feature-requests/suggestions/32003005-extract-export-css-for-development-feature) and this).

Also I think you can also use a plugin called "Web Export."

In order to use the plugin,

Make sure you have the latest version of XD

1. Go to Plugins
2. Discover Plugins
3. Search "Web Export"
4. Click "Install"

Comment: The link says that they have added the feature in August. so now maybe we can use it. I hope the results convert to CSS exactly the same as the prototype that was made

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward option is to write the html/css by hand and then manually integrate it with vue components.

But since you said you are not that proficient at css, you can use Desech Studio to import the AdobeXD file, then make some adjustments, install the vue plugin in Desech Studio and then it will integrate your html/css code with vue directly.

Check the github repo at https://github.com/desech/studio-vue to see tips and the limitations of the plugin.